# SPFx define custom config folder for building solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, typescript

Is it possible, to somehow define which config folder gulp will take while bundling. Saying i will have a build script for each sppkg solutions

```
gulp clean && gulp bundle --ship && gulp package-solution --ship --cfg-webpart-one
```

and gulp then knows that he take config-webpart-one folder which contain package-solution.json and config.json, configured for webpart-one bundle.

Default folder structure is:

```
config
src
...
```

With multiple configs will be

```
config-webpart-one
config-webpart-two
src
...
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?